# linux script shell : grep a part of path in a list of path

Tags: linux, shell, grep

In my script shell, i have 2 files. The first one is a file containing only names of files with part of the path :

list1:

```
aaa/bbb/file1.ext
ccc/ddd/file2.ext
eee/fff/file3.ext
```

The second one is a list of every files of the extension ".ext" with the absolute path before them:

list2:

```
/home/.../aaa/bbb/file1.ext
...
...
...
/home/...ccc/ddd/file2.ext
...
```

And I am trying to extract the lines of the second file list2, containing the lines of the first one with grep.

For now I tried :

```
while read line
do
    grep "$line" "list1" 
done < list2
```

But this command doesn't ouptut anything, however the command

```
grep "aaa/bbb/file1.ext" "list1"
```

have the output I am waiting for

```
/home/.../aaa/bbb/file1.ext
```

Anyone sees what I am missing on this script? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the cases where `-f` option from `grep` comes very handy:

```
grep -f f1 f2
```

For your given input returns:

```
/home/.../aaa/bbb/file1.ext
/home/...ccc/ddd/file2.ext
```

From `man grep`:

> **-f FILE**, --file=FILE
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero
>   patterns, and  therefore  matches  nothing. (-f is specified by
>   POSIX.)

Comment: It seems to be a good solution but it doesn't work in my case... There is no output again.

Comment: Can you provide a more specific input?

Comment: In fact the test you made with my exemple files worked perfectly for me, so I think I have to check the way I created my files to perform this command. Thanks for the answer

Comment: +1 : Good answer and explanation sorry for misunderstanding of question though and can't reply due to connectivity issue. @fedorqui

Comment: Thanks @Skynet ! This is very nice from you. Note your answer was missing the `read` part. In general, to read a file safely you will do `while IFS= read -r line; do ... ; done < file`. `IFS=` sets the field separator to the space and `-r` avoids problems if some fields contain slashes.